# Counting cycles in undirected graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to write a program that given adjacency matrix of an undirected graph, computes the number of cycles of different sizes using matrix operations and linear algebra. I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Matrix_powers) that

> If $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the directed or undirected graph $G$,
> then the matrix $A^n$ has an
> interesting interpretation: the element $(i, j)$ gives the number of
> (directed or undirected) walks of length $n$ from vertex $i$ to vertex $j$.
> If $n$ is the smallest nonnegative integer, such that for some $i$, $j$, the
> element $(i, j)$ of $A^n$ is positive, then n is the distance between
> vertex $i$ and vertex $j$.

The text concludes that

> This implies, for example, that the number of triangles in an undirected
> graph $G$ is exactly the trace of $A^3$ divided by $6$.

I was wondering if this can be extended to cycles of larger size.

Comment: depending on what you mean by cycle. v -> u -> v -> u -> v is a length 4 cycle for you?

Comment: @Exodd a closed loop with non-repeating nodes and edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangles are special in this regard.

The only possible closed walk of length $3$ is a 3-cycle, so the only closed walks from a vertex to itself counted by $A^3$ are the desired cycles.

However for longer closed walks, not all of these are cycles. For all $k>3$, there exists at least one up-to-isomorphism closed walk that is not a cycle. (Exodd's example shows you how to find ones of even length).

Comment: That makes sense. To clarify, 1) there is no other way to count the number of cycles based on matrix powers and without search algorithms then? 2) Can we check if an edge is part of a closed walk of any size using adjacency matrix powers?

Comment: I don't know the answers to either of those questions. Only that this specific counting method of counting triangles doesn't work for other cycles.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. So when you say "Triangles are special in this regard" what is the general case? What is the $Tr(A^4)$ showing for instance? Is it number of closed walks of size $4$ that are not necessarily a cycle? If so, what should I divide it by? Where did that $6$ come from in $Tr(A^3)/6$? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, each element $A_{i,i}$ of the diagonal of $A^k$ is the number of closed walks starting and ending at vertex $v_i$. The division gets much more complicated, because you can have 'the same closed walk' traversed in very many different ways, depending on the walk. The $6$ comes from the fact that each $3$-cycle contains $3$ vertices, and can be walked in two different ways. For example, the 3-cycle $u,v,w,u$ will be counted twice by $u$ as both $u,v,w,u$ and $u,w,v,u$ (same cycle, two different walks, repeat this on 3 vertices). So in total the trace counts each 3-cycle $6$ times.