# counting cycles and paths in simple graphs

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, graph-theory, algorithms, planar-graphs

I'm newly studying graphs in my school courses and I've been facing this common type of questions about how many cycles/paths are there between some vertices I asked my teacher for a simpler or more algorithmic way to count them but he said except for Kn graphs. so I started to search for such an algorithms and I found out there are such algorithms but I have no idea how to use them(as I said I'm a high-school student).
these are the papers I took a look at:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0020019094001510
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.156.345
so I'm seeking a way to solve such problems more efficiently and with less probability of making ridiculous mistakes.
any help is appreciated

Comment: You mean that you want to solve the problems more efficiently than the way described in these two articles?

Comment: @NickL No, I don't insist on using these articles but I provided them as some possible ways for this.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902084/counting-cycles-in-undirected-graphs) question can be helpful.

Comment: @AlexRavsky thanks, I will read it.and I will post any conclusion I got here or in a new post.