# Count the number of k-cycles in adjacency matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

I am looking for a method or formula for finding the number of cycles of length k starting at A in the following graph:

[image]

From what I have read there is formulas for undirected graphs without restrictions on where the cycle starts, I found [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphCycle.html) in a similar question. However I didn't find anything on directed graphs starting at a certain vertex. The idea of finding the number of cycles for this graph is to later find a formula for the number of k cycles in graphs with the same structure as the one above (one vertex at the top, then a n by n grid without the bottom edges and finally one last vertex) given the size of n. For example the graph above would be n=3 and n=4 would look like:

[image]

Comment: The provided graphs are not directed. It is a combination of directed and undirected edges, is that intended?

Comment: @DavidScholz A graph that has both directed and undirected edges is directed. Another way of seeing it is there is 2 edges, one in one direction the other in the other direction for every non-directed edge.

Comment: So for every undirected edge in your picture, there are actually two directed edges in reverse direction but with the same endpoints. A graph that has both directed and undirected edges is called a mixed graph. Thanks for the explanation. That wasn’t clear.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3902084/counting-cycles-in-undirected-graphs) question can be helpful.